# Validating where the "@" symbol is in an email. Not validation of the email itself

Tags: python, python-3.x, character, email-validation

"it must contain an “@” symbol
which is NEITHER the first character nor the last character in the string."

So I have this assignment in my class and I can't for the life of me figure out how to make the boolean false for having it at the front or end of the email. This is what I have so far.

```
def validEmail1(myString):
    for i in myString:
        if i == "@":
            return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `s` as your string, you can do:

```
not (s.endswith('@') or s.startswith('@')) and s.count('@')==1
```

Test:

```
def valid(s):
    return not (s.endswith('@') or s.startswith('@')) and s.count('@')==1

cases=('@abc','abc@','abc@def', 'abc@@def')

for case in cases:
    print(case, valid(case))
```

Prints:

```
@abc False
abc@ False
abc@def True
abc@@def False
```

---

You can also use a slice, but you also need to make sure (indirectly) that the string does not start or end with `'@'` by making sure the count is 1:

```
def valid(s):
    return '@' in s[1:-1] and s.count('@')==1
```

Comment: This is the actual correct answer. The other answer checks everything but the first and last. You could also use `return "@" not in [s[0], s[-1]] ..`

Comment: Why do you assume the count has to be 1? Valid e-mail addresses can have multiple (quoted) `@` symbols...